# Can I use Mongo's partial indexes to index only latest records?

Tags: mongodb

For example if I have 10000000 records in a collection, can I add conditional index that covers only records added during last 2 weeks?

Comment: Not if you're looking for a sliding "last 2 weeks".

Comment: *"These are not the droids you are looking for"*. If you have an extremely large amount of data then the better options are to keep the "most recent" data in a separate collection to "history" or implement sharding in such a way which favors distribution on a "recent" tag. In the latter case you probably need more resources than you presently have, so it's typically a much larger problem than can be addressed in a single sentence.